# Mysql query CONCAT change the output

Tags: php, mysql, sql, concatenation

I have the following query:

```
mysql> select (select m.delay from messages m order by message_id desc limit 1) as Delay, s.min_delay, s.max_delay from statistics s order by s.date_hour desc limit 1;
+-------+-----------+-----------+
| Delay | min_delay | max_delay |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
|    10 |      7.00 |     12.00 |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Which is fine. But I need to get the results in the following format:

```
 Delay=10 Min_Delay=7.00 Max_Delay=12.00
```

Can I do that using concat?

Comment: Do you mean for each row? Or you just want 1 line that looks like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you would do that transformation at the application layer.  However, you can do it in MySQL if you want using `concat()`:

```
select concat_ws(' ',
                 concat('Delay=', (select m.delay from messages m order by message_id desc limit 1)),
                 concat('Min_Delay=', s.min_delay),
                 concat('Max_Delay=', s.max_delay)
                )
from statistics s
order by s.date_hour desc
limit 1
```